# How to reference textbox from gridview in my codebehind C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

All the examples I've found have not been helpful.  I have a textbox in the footer of my gridview called "txtMyCoverage".  In my codebehind I just want to reference that textbox  to say

```
a = txtMyCoverage.Text;
```

I tried

```
gvLimit.FindControl("txtMyCoverage").ToString();
```

but it comes back null reference.  Thanks for any help!

Here is my grid

```
<asp:GridView Width="100%" ID="gvLimits"
CssClass="gridView no_min_width"
runat="server"
AutoGenerateColumns="False"
CellPadding="2" ShowFooter="true"
DataKeyNames="PolicyLimitID, LimitID"
HorizontalAlign="Center"
OnRowDataBound="gvLimits_RowDataBound">
<RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Coverage">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="txtLimitLetter" runat="server" Width="20px" CssClass="center" Text='<%# Bind("Limit.LimitLetter") %>' Enabled="false" ></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtMyCoverage" runat="server" Width="50px" CssClass="center" ></asp:TextBox>
        </FooterTemplate>

</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to convert a control into a string?

Comment: can you show how you have the txtMyCoverage defined in the Markup do you have runat="" and do you have an ID assigned..? please give / show more information

Comment: Show us your HTML code (DataGrid). have you add the runat="Server" attribute?

Comment: I've added the grid code..took out the other columns so it wouldn't be so long.  @MelanciaUK I'm just trying to get the text from that textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if You Used TextBox Like this:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Coverage">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="txtLimitLetter" runat="server" Width="20px" CssClass="center" Text='<%# Bind("Limit.LimitLetter") %>' Enabled="false" ></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtMyCoverage" runat="server" Width="50px" CssClass="center" ></asp:TextBox>
        </FooterTemplate>
```

then it You can find On rowbound like this:

On RowBoundEvent of Grid

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
{
TextBox txtLimitLetter=(TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtLimitLetter");
}

}
```

or
you can Look Through GridView Rows

```
foreach(GridViewRow row in GridView2.Rows)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
    TextBox txtLimitLetter=(TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtLimitLetter");
    }

}
```